# node express submission over https JSON not formatted

Tags: node.js, body-parser

I have an angularjs app posting over https to a node express server. The angular client is posting with the header:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
```

On the server:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
```

This produces a request body that looks like:

```
{ '{"firstname":"hj","lastname":"hj"}': '' }
```

Without bodyParser I don't get any body at all.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. Is there a way to get valid json without trying to unscramble the above request body?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're missing is to let bodyParser be aware of `JSON`.

```
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  // Place it below ^ your urlencoded line

  app.use(bodyParser.json()); // <-- this
```

Comment: No, I tried that and the request body was the same. I did forget to mention in my question that the angular post includes the header 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Change angular to application/json, that should do it

Answer (score 0):

MarkPieszak is right in his post and in his comment:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
```

I somehow didn't think this would work over https